# ListView Grow instead of Scroll

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

Is there a way (without codebehind) to make a WPF ListView grow to the width or height of its contents rather than scroll?  Sort of like a StackPanel only still selectable.

For instance, if I have:

```
<ScrollViewer>
  <StackPanel>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Rail1}">
      <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Rail2}">
      <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
  </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

the ScrollViewer does not show a horizontal scroll bar, instead the ListViews do.

Comment: Do you have any styles or anything else set on `ListViews`? Or some special data in `Rail1`, `Rail2`? Your sample works fine if you add `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"` into scrollViewer.

Comment: Sorry.  I forgot to mention that I used a StackPanel as the ItemsPanel for the listview.  I'm trying to get the growth to be horizontal, not vertical.  Maybe a StackPanel isn't the correct choice for ItemsPanel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on container. Add `ListView` itself to the `ScrollViewer` - it should do the trick.

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <StackPanel>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Rail1}" > 
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        </ListView>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Rail2}" >
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Counterintuitively, once I set the HorizontalScrollBarVisibility to auto, it worked.  I figured that would happen implicitly, but apparently not.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on it's container, but if you set the `HorizontalAlignment` property to `"Stretch"` and the ListView's container will allow it, it should size itself to its content.

*** Edit ****
If you want both ListView's not to scroll then do something like:

```
<ScrollViewer>
   <DockPanel>
      <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Rail1}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
      <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Rail2}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
   </DockPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I think this will give you what you want.

Comment: Please see my above edit.  Is a StackPanel the wrong control to use as a container inside of the ScrollViewer?